# Sweet Alerts with BeginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sweetalert, html.beginform

I have a standard forgot password form in MVC

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ForgotPassword", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Enter your email.</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Email Link" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

What I would like to do is instead of redirecting a user to a separate Html page when the forgot password link is clicked, I would like a SweetAlerts box to pop up where the user can input their email to send a password reset link.

Answer (score 0):

swal({
  content: {
    element: "input",
    attributes: {
      placeholder: "Enter your email",
      type: "text",
    },
  },
});